# In Windows SkyDrive, is there a way to the get direct link to 'Open in <full client>'?

Tags: office-365, onedrive

Let's say you have an Excel file in SkyDrive.  Right now the only way I can figure out how to open it directly in the full Excel application is to open in on the web first and then click the 'Open in Excel' button.

[image]

Right clicking on the button and copying the link doesn't work.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

When you select an Excel file. "Open in Excel" will display on the right side

Comment: Thanks.  I tried, but creating a bookmark from that link has the same problem as the one outlined in the question.

Comment: Oh,have you solved the question?  When I selected one of my Excel file with checkbox, not clicked on its name. Some marks appear on the right side. For examples,"View in browser","Edit in browser","Open in Excel"...Is there anything difference between our pages?

Comment: Yes.  Those links appear.  Try right clicking on the 'Edit in browser' link and copying it.  Then paste it in a Word document or somewhere else where it can be made clickable.  When it is clicked it will not open the file in Excel.  It will open it in the browser.

Comment: Ok, Why need you copy the link? There is an 'Open in Excel' link under the 'Edit in browser' link in my page. If you also have one, Try left clicking on "Open in Excel" link.

Comment: And you may like working with the 'Thumbnails view'(look at the two icons after 'Bing Search'). With this 'Thumbnails view' state, you can right click on your excel file, and then click 'Open in Excel'...

Comment: Spring, thanks for the help.  Have you actually tried what you're recommending?  It doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. Before answering your question, I have tested them again, both of the methods. And it really works. Sorry for nothing helped...